# Why the interface is not getting updated using Swift Data and Dictionary?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

My @Model has a property, it's a dictionary of arrays and the key is Date Components by year and month. It's the only way that I found to not get super slow lists or lazyStacks with medium amount of data.

The thing is the type of the arrays in the dictionary could not be @Model because I need them to be codable but they are on my main model. But when something changes the UI is not refreshing.

```
@Model
class Pet: Identifiable { //This is my main class

    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id = UUID()
    ...
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var feeds: [DateComponents:[Feed]]
    ...
}
```

```
class Feed: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Observable {
    static func == (lhs: Feed, rhs: Feed) -> Bool {
        lhs.startDate == rhs.startDate && lhs.id == rhs.id && ...
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(startDate)
        ...
    }
    
    var id = UUID()
    var startDate: Date
    ...
    var latest: Bool {
        if self.dateComponents == Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from:Date()) {
            return true
        } else { return false }
    }
}
```

Then in my view, I have a Foreach, that get the rows and when you click a row you go to an Edit View where you can change data. All works great the thing is, when I use dictionary instead of an array for example, the UI does not get updated automatically, not even if I change the day of the device (that should change everything), It only loads the data correctly once and then, everything is have to be done manually.

```
struct Feed_View: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var pet: Pet
    
    var feedsByDate:[Feed]{
        (pet.feeds[Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from:Date())] ?? []).sorted(by: {$0.startDate > $1.startDate})
    }
...
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
}
...
ForEach(feedsByDate, id: \.id) { feed in
       {
         Row(feed: feed, pet: Pet)
       }
...
```

Comment: Observable  should be used as a Macro

Comment: @loremipsum nope, it not makes any difference marking the class with the macro Observable

Comment: What do you think about this?
https://www.donnywals.com/making-your-swiftdata-models-codable/

Comment: @Dinox Thanks! I tried it, it helped a little bit when I manually update my feeds and rewrite them into my Pets model. But it didn't help updating automatically the UI. I also tried to give the Model attribute to my Feed class but it made it unbearable slow. (I will be having medium amounts of data of that type around 5,000) so I think it's better to keep it this way, and update manually the Baby.feeds[:[feed]] and that does the trick with the UI update.